# Using form submit handler in jQueryMobile for validation, but preventing sending

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-mobile, submit, action

I'm building an app in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap. I have an approach to validate forms that works nicely while testing in Chrome and on my Nexus S Android phone, but that I'm not sure will work on all devices.

This is the situation:

I have a few simple forms. The data that the user enters is stored locally. So I don't need POST or GET requests (in fact, I want to avoid them like the plague). I could just create a few inputs and a button and add a click handler to the button for everything to work nicely.

Except I really like the HTML5 form validation stuff. And that validation only (mostly) takes place when the submit event is fired on the form. So I have chosen to put the inputs and the button inside a form element, make one button a submit button, and listen for the submit event being fired on the form.
Another approach (shown here for the 'Delete' button) is to simply listen for a click on the button without making any use of the submit process. After all, if a user wants to delete an item, there is no need to validate the form (in my case anyway).

```
<form id="oneExpenseForm" action="javascript:void(0);" method=''>
    <button type="submit" id="submitExpense">Save</button>
    <button id="deleteExpense">Delete</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('#oneExpenseForm').on('submit',function(){
        submitExpense();//This function takes care of everything I want
    })
</script>
```

This seems to work fine. I've also tried setting the form action differently:

```
<form id="oneExpenseForm" action="submit" method=''>
```

But that caused the browser to start a GET request, which causes a page reload (which is a really bad and unwanted thing when working with jQueryMobile).

What I'm worried about is that I may be setting things up for failure in certain browsers. After all, some browsers might see this action attribute...

```
  action="javascript:void(0);"
```

...as a reason to not fire the submit event at all. That would be bad, since I need the submit event to fire for validation and

Am I taking needless risks here? Or do all browsers fire the submit event even when the form action is set to null, void, etc?

One more thing:
I could of course just specify...

```
action="javascript:submitExpense();"
```

...in the HTML file. But this is something that I want to avoid, since I am protecting my Js code with obfuscation. That involves changing the names of functions to unreadable code like aR3df(); using a special piece of software. I would prefer not to have to look up the obfuscated names and enter them in the HTML every time I am publishing an update.

EDIT:
After the first answer came in to use e.preventDefault() and that did not work, I figured it might be relevant that I am binding the submit event handler inside another function. That's because jQueryMobile wants you to only do your custom handling stuff after the "page" has been initialized. 
In previous jQuery versions it didn't work to use the .live() binder within other functions. But this is not the problem either. Even when I bind the handler the ".live()" way using the new .on() binder...

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#oneExpensePage',function(event){
    $('#oneExpenseForm').on('submit',function(){
        submitExpense();//This function takes care of everything I want
    })
})
```

... the page reload (i.e. form submit) persists.

Answer (score 0):

Leave action empty `action=""` and [prevent the event's default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on submit:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#oneExpenseForm').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        submitExpense();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks streetPC, but it didn't work. I set action on the form to ="" and made the script as you suggested, but the page still reloads with the form fields in the URL.

Comment: I checked if it was anything to do with me binding the handler inside another event handler, but that was not the problem either. e.preventDefault() just does not prevent the default in this situation.

Comment: Try to use `$(function(){...});` as I edited above rather than pageinit, I think the binding code it is never called.

Comment: BTW `$(<function>)` is a shortcut for `$(document.ready(<function>))`

Comment: Hi StreetPC, the handler is called all right. If I put in a console.info I can see that. $(document).on('pageinit','#oneExpense') is the equivalent of .live(), so it is bound-in-advance even if the element does not exist yet when the function is run.

Comment: It may be, but it is uselessly costly to bind in advance when you can avoid it. Just wait for the DOM to be ready (not fully _loaded_ like `onLoad`, just ready). 
The method given above works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wp4Pn/

Comment: If this solved your problem, consider marking it as an accepted answer so that others can find it.

Comment: Well, the original question is still unanswered: am I taking needless risks by binding a submit event handler when simultaneously setting the form action to "javascript:void(0)". Are there no browsers that will take the void thingy as a reason not to fire the submit event?